# Single Linked List with Generic Implementation

Tags: c#, generics, linked-list

I have created a single linked list with generic implementation. But the Add(..) method is giving compilation error saying:

> Error 4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'ds.MyNode< T >' to 'ds.MyNode<
>   T >'

Following the code implementation:

```
public class MyNode<T>
{
    public MyNode(T content)
    {
        Content = content;
    }
    public T Content { get; set; }
    public MyNode<T> Next { get; set; }
}
public class MyLinkedList<T>
{
    private int size;
    private MyNode<T> head;
    private MyNode<T> tail;

    public MyNode<T> Tail
    {
        get { return tail; }
        set { tail = value; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return size; }
        set { size = value; }
    }

    public MyNode<T> Head
    {
        get { return head; }
        set { head = value; }
    }

    public void Add<T>(MyNode<T> node)
    {
        size++;
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = tail = node;
        }
        else
        {               
            tail.Next = node;
            tail = node;
        }
    }       
}
```

I'm not sure what am I missing here, The error is confusing because both the types it says aren't implicitly convertible are same. Any help is appreciated.

I am compiling it against .Net 4.0

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you want those setters to be public

Comment: Yeah I agree, but it was just a sample code for posting on SE, so the props are auto-generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the `<T>` generic type from `Add` method, since your class is already generic.

It is possible for class and method to have the same name of generic type ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)):

> If you define a **generic method** that takes the **same type parameters as the containing class**, the compiler generates **warning CS0693** because
>   within the method scope, **the argument supplied for the inner T hides
>   the argument supplied for the outer T**. If you require the
>   flexibility of calling a generic class method with type arguments
>   other than the ones provided when the class was instantiated,
>   **consider providing another identifier for the type parameter of the method**, as shown in `GenericList2<T>` in the following example.
>
> ```
> class GenericList<T>
> {
>     // CS0693 
>     void SampleMethod<T>() { }
> }
>
> class GenericList2<T>
> {
>     //No warning 
>     void SampleMethod<U>() { }
> }
> ```

So, you should probably enable compile warnings. [Example of the compiler output from ideone.com](https://ideone.com/8ZScww):

```
prog.cs(39,22): warning CS0693: Type parameter `T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type `Test.MyLinkedList<T>'
prog.cs(15,28): (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
prog.cs(44,28): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Test.MyNode<T> [prog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]' to `Test.MyNode<T> [prog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]'
prog.cs(48,26): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Test.MyNode<T> [prog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]' to `Test.MyNode<T> [prog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]'
prog.cs(49,21): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Test.MyNode<T> [prog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]' to `Test.MyNode<T> [prog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]'
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 1 warnings
```

Comment: yeah since I was using same generic identifier 'T' for both inner and outer declaration, it confused me to figure out the error. Had I used different identifiers the solution would have struck me early. Thanks for explanation. Also ignoring this warning wasn't wise. :)

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
public void Add<T>(MyNode<T> node)
```

Means that `T` is over shadowing your class level T declaration, hence the compiler looks at them as different types. Removing `T` will work, as it is clear that you want your classes `T` declaration.

Just so you visually see it, this will work as well **(don't use this)**:

```
public void Add<TOther>(MyNode<T> node) where TOther : T
```

Since you're now explicitly telling the compiler `TOther` is of type `T` or derived.